# How to select only names starting with a specific letter other than with the like function in proc sql (SAS)

Tags: sql

```
proc sql;
    select state, income
    from geography
    where state like "M%"
quit;
```

In mysql, I know you can use charindex and substring but they do not work in SAS/proc sql. Any assistance will be helpful.

Comment: In a procedure ```SELECT``` needs to be ```INTO``` something.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited it now

Comment: Thats good that you are selecting ```FROM``` a table now, but you are still not selecting ```INTO``` anything.  In a procedure the output needs to be inserted somewhere.  It cannot be selected into the ether.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use comparisons:

```
where state >= 'M' and state < 'N'
```

String comparisons work.